# Predicate Logic with Inequality

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have the following sentence which I have to formalize using first-order logic.

"All #'s greater than or equal to one are greater than themselves divided by four"

Is it correct to say:
∀x(x≥1) → (x > x/4)

If so, would the negation be:
∃x¬(x≥1) ∧ ¬(x > x/4)

If this isn't correct, how would I be able to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

the quantifier must cover the entire formula:
$$
\forall x\left(x\geq1\rightarrow x>\frac{x}{4}\right)
$$

Comment: So then the negation would be:  ∃x(x≥1 ∧ ¬(x>x/4)), correct? The inequality symbol doesn't change when negating?

Comment: @CarmineReddit Negation form: $\neg\exists x(x\geq 1\wedge x\leq x/4)$

Comment: $∃x ¬ (x≥1 → x > \dfrac x 4)$